# Is it possible for a discord bot to enter a foreign server?

Tags: discord.js

I'm using discord.js and I want to create a bot to retreive all the links of a certain channel, but I don't know if it's posible enter to a foreign server with the dicord api, for example join to this server https://discordapp.com/invite/C89qHyt.

Edited:

if it is posible, how I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a bot account, the client can't enter a server on its own. You have to use [OAuth2](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#bots) to invite the bot to the server. You'll also need the `MANAGE_SERVER` permission in the server you're trying to add the bot to.

To generate the invite link for your bot, [this site](https://discordapi.com/permissions.html) may prove very useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can't just add a bot to a group with no invite or permission.

Comment: And how I do that ?

Comment: you need to ask the admin to add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it join. You have to create a invite link and let the server admin to invite it.

Comment: Please avoid using external links to show your code. Instead, please [edit] your answer to include code that is relevant to the question in the answer itself. Answers that are little more than links to external sites may end up being [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).